# AS3, Mouse Over even when something is above movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say there is a TOP movieclip

and another BOTTOM movieclip

How would I trigger a mouse event when the mouse is over BOTTOM even if TOP is overlaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want any mouse events for the top one, set mouseEnabled to false for the top clip.

```
topClip.mouseEnabled= false;
```

Comment: Nice work around! Thanks. If no one can give a better answer, I'll accept this one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the only way to do it. The top clip is blocking the mouse from interacting with the one below.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can also be the solution if you don't want your topClip mouse disabled OR if you want to receive your mouse event on both movie clips.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function onMouseOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(evt.currentTarget==bottomClip)
                {
                    Alert.show(bottomClip+" CLICKED");
                }
                if(evt.currentTarget==topClip)
                {
                    Alert.show(topClip+" CLICKED");
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas id="can" width="600" height="400" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" borderStyle="solid" borderColor="red" >
        <mx:Canvas id="bottomClip" click="onMouseOver(event)">
            <mx:Canvas id="actualBottomClip" width="400" height="300" x="100" y="50" backgroundColor="red" />
            <mx:Canvas id="topClip" click="onMouseOver(event)">
                <mx:Canvas id="actualTopClip" width="200" height="75" x="50" y="100" backgroundColor="green" />
            </mx:Canvas>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```